# VbScript, Install exe remotely without user input?

Tags: windows, vbscript, exe, silent-installer

I'm really stuck on a problem so I figured I would get a second opinion(s).

I'm trying to remotely install .exe and .msi to client computers.  I have a vb script that downloads the file and runs the file, but there's a few problems.  First, I'm having trouble getting it to the run on the local admin account.  For testing purposes I'm running it as an Admin and it works fine, but if put on a client computer it would need access to the local Admin.

Secondly, and more importantly, microsoft requires some amount of user input before installing an exe file.  I know silent msi install is possible, but I assume silent exe is impossible?

As a solution I'm looking into PsExec, but I feel like I'm missing something here.

For reference, here is my vb script:

```
Dim TApp
Dim IEObj
Dim tArea
Dim tButton

Const HIDDEN_WINDOW = 12 
Const SHOW_WINDOW=1 

'Array of Patch files to install.
Dim InstallFiles() 

'maximum of 100 workstations to install patches to.
Dim wsNames(100) 
Dim numComputers 
Dim retVal 
Dim PatchFolder 
'Create explorer window
Set IEObj=CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEObj.Navigate "about:blank"
IEObj.Height=400
IEObj.Width=500
IEObj.MenuBar=False
IEObj.StatusBar=False
IEObj.ToolBar=0
set outputWin=IEObj.Document
outputWin.Writeln "<title>RemotePatchInstall version 1.0</title>"
outputWin.writeln "<HTA:APPLICATION ID='objPatchomatic' APPLICATIONNAME='Patchomatic' SCROLL='no' SINGLEINSTANCE='yes' WINDOWSTATE='normal'>"

outputWin.writeln "<BODY bgcolor=ButtonFace ScrollBar='No'>"
outputWin.writeln "<TABLE cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=1 width='75pt' border=1>" 
outputWin.writeln "<TBODY>"

outputWin.writeln "<TR>"
outputWin.writeln "<TD>"
outputWin.writeln "<P align=center><TEXTAREA name=Information rows=6 cols=57 style='WIDTH: 412px; HEIGHT: 284px'></TEXTAREA></P></TD></TR>"
outputWin.writeln "<TR>"
'   outputWin.writeln "<TD><P align=center><INPUT id=button1 style='WIDTH: 112px; HEIGHT: 24px' type=button size=38 value='Install Patches' name=button1></P></TD>"
outputWin.writeln "</TR>"
outputWin.writeln "<TR>"
outputWin.writeln "<TD></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>"
outputWin.writeln "</BODY>"

IEObj.Visible=True
'Get the Information textarea object from the window
set tempObj=outputWin.getElementsByName("Information")
objFound=false
'loop through its object to find what we need
For each objN in tempObj
if objN.name="Information" then
objFound=true
set tArea=objN
end if
next
'if we didnt find the object theres a problem
if ObjFound=False then
'so show an error and bail
MsgBox "Unable to access the TextBox on IE Window",32,"Error"
WScript.Quit
end if



'************************* 
'ADMINS: The below is all you should really have to change. 
'************************* 

'Change this to the location of the patches that will be installed. 
'they should be limited to the amout you try to install at one time. 
'ALSO the order they are installed is how explorer would list them by alphabetically. 
'So given file names:
'patch1.exe
'patch2.exe
'patch11.exe
'installation order would be patch1.exe,patch11.exe, patch2.exe

PatchFolder="C:\IUware Online\Install\" 

'Change this to location where the patches will be copied to on remote cp. This directory must exist on remote computer.
'I have it hidden on all workstations.
RemotePatchFolder="C:\Users\jorblume\Backup\" 

'Workstation names to refer to as array 
wsNames(1)="129.79.205.153" 
'wsNames(2)="192.168.0.11" 

'number of remote computers
numComputers=1 
'**********************
'ADMINS: The above is all you should really have to change. 
'********************** 

'Copy files to remote computers. 

'Get a list of the executable file in the folder and put them into the InstallFiles array 
'on return, retVal will be number of files found. 
retVal=GetPatchFileList (PatchFolder,InstallFiles) 

'for each file copy to remote computers 
For cc=1 to numComputers 'for each computer 
For i = 1 to retVal 'for each file 
Dim copySuccess
Dim SharedDriveFolder 
'do a replacement on the : to $, this means you must have admin priv 
'this is because i want to copy to "\\remotecpname\c$\PathName" 
SharedDriveFolder=replace(RemotePatchFolder,":","$") 
'copy it from the PatchFolder to the path on destination computer 
'USE: RemoteCopyFile (SourceFilePath,DestinationFilePath, RemoteComputerName) 
CurrentCP=cc 
copySuccess=RemoteCopyFile(PatchFolder & "\" & InstallFiles(i),SharedDriveFolder,wsNames(CurrentCP))
if copySuccess=true then
tArea.Value=tArea.Value & PatchFolder & "\" & InstallFiles(i) & " copy - OK" & vbcrlf
else
tArea.Value=tArea.Value & PatchFolder & "\" & InstallFiles(i) & " copy - FAILED" & vbcrlf
end if
Next 
Next 


'Install the files on remote computer 

'go through each filename and start that process on remote PC.
'for each file install them on the computers. 
For cc=1 to numComputers 

'if theres more than one patch 
if retVal>1 then 
For i=1 to retVal-1
CurrentCp=cc 

'Now create a process on remote computer 
'USE: CreateProcessandwait( ComputerName, ExecutablePathonRemoteComputer 
'Create a process on the remote computer and waits. Now this can return a program terminated which is ok,
'if it returns cancelled it means the process was stopped, this could happen if the update required a 
'computer restart. 

CreateProcessandWait wsNames(CurrentCP), RemotePatchFolder & InstallFiles(i) & " /quiet /norestart", tArea

next 
end if

'do the last patch with a forcereboot 
CreateProcessandWait wsNames(CurrentCP), RemotePatchFolder & InstallFiles(retVal) & " /quiet" & " /forcereboot" , tArea

next 

tArea.value=tArea.Value & "Script Complete!" & vbcrlf


'****************************    FUNCTIONS 

'Get list of files in Folder.

Function GetPatchFileList(FileFolder, FileStringArray()) 

'create file system object 
Set objFS=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
'set the a variable to point to our folder with the patches in it. 
Set objFolder=objFS.GetFolder(FileFolder) 
'set the initial file count to 0 
numPatches=0 

for each objFile in objFolder.Files 
if UCase(Right(objFile.Name,4))=".EXE" then 
numPatches=numPatches+1 

redim preserve FileStringArray(numPatches) 
FileStringArray(numPatches)=objFile.Name 
end if 

next 
GetPatchFileList=numPatches 
End Function 

'Copy files to remote computer.

Function RemoteCopyFile(SrcFileName,DstFileName,DestinationComputer) 
Dim lRetVal 
'create file system object 
Set objFS=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

lRetVal=objFS.CopyFile (SrcFileName, "\\" & DestinationComputer & "\" & DstFileName) 
if lRetVal=0 then 
RemoteCopyFile=True 
else 
RemoteCopyFile=False 
end if 
End Function 


'Create process on remote computer and wait for it to complete.

Function CreateProcessAndWait(DestinationComputer,ExecutableFullPath,OutPutText) 
Dim lretVal 

strComputer= DestinationComputer 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
Set objWMIServiceStart= GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_ProcessStartup")

Set objConfig = objWMIServiceStart.SpawnInstance_ 

objConfig.ShowWindow = 1 'show window or use HIDDEN_WINDOW 



lretVal= objWMIService.Create(ExecutableFullPath, null, objConfig, intProcessID) 
if lretVal=0 then 
OutPutText.Value = OutPutText.Value & "Process created with ID of " & intProcessID & " on " & DestinationComputer & vbcrlf
OutPutText.Value = OutPutText.Value & " Waiting for process " & intProcessID & " to complete." & vbcrlf 

WaitForPID strComputer, intProcessID,OutPutText
OutPutText.Value = OutPutText.Value & "Process complete." & vbcrlf
else 
OutPutText.Value = OutPutText.Value & "Unable to start process " & ExecutableFullPath & " on " & DestinationComputer & vbcrlf
end if 
End Function 


'Wait for PRocess to complete

Function WaitForPID(ComputerName,PIDNUMBER,OutPutText) 
Dim ProcessNumber 

Set objWMIServiceQ = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & ComputerName & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colItems = objWMIServiceQ.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process",,48) 
For Each objItem in colItems 
'check if this process is the one we are waiting for 
if objItem.ProcessID=PIDNUMBER then 
OutPutText.Value = OutPutText.Value & "Process Info:" & vbcrlf 
OutPutText.Value = OutPutText.Value & " Description: " & objItem.Description & vbcrlf 
OutPutText.Value = OutPutText.Value & " ExecutablePath: " & objItem.ExecutablePath & vbcrlf 
OutPutText.Value = OutPutText.Value & " Name: " & objItem.Name & vbcrlf 
OutPutText.Value = OutPutText.Value & " Status: " & objItem.Status & vbcrlf 
OutPutText.Value = OutPutText.Value & " ThreadCount: " & objItem.ThreadCount & vbcrlf 
ProcessNumber=objItem.ProcessID 
end if 

Next 

PidWaitSQL="SELECT TargetInstance.ProcessID " & " FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 4 " _ 
& "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND " _ 
& "TargetInstance.ProcessID= '" & ProcessNumber & "'" 

Set Events = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & ComputerName & "\root\cimv2").ExecNotificationQuery (PidWaitSQL)



Set TerminationEvent = Events.nextevent 
OutPutText.Value = OutPutText.Value & "Program " & TerminationEvent.TargetInstance.ProcessID & _ 
" terminated. " & vbcrlf
set TerminationEvent=Nothing 
exit function 

End Function
```

Comment: I think you'll need to use psexec for this.

Comment: Many exe-based installers can run silently, but you need to know the right command line parameters.  For example, most MS software updates can be installed silently by specifying /passive /norestart.

Comment: Depending on your design goals, alternatives to using psexec would include running your code as a startup script or as a system service.

Comment: (I assume you are aware that there are lots of commercial solutions available that address this exact problem?)

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks for the feedback!  Yes, there ARE commercial solutions to this, but they're fairly expensive, and I'm running on a non-existent budget.  So, in light of lack of funds I'm trying to make do with scripts.  I'll try psexec!

Comment: I guess along those lines, does anyone know enough about psexec to give me some pointer?  I'm having trouble getting the file to run silently, but the -i command doesn't yield any results                     For reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553                                            http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/remote-computing/psexec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, psexec will be your best solution for this scenario. Just don't forget to use /accepteula in its syntax to ensure it doesn't effectively "hang" while waiting for someone to accept its EULA. :) If you have questions or issues with psexec in your installs, comment back here.